# When appending one vector to another, why is moving the elements any cheaper than copying them?

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say that I have two vectors, `src` and `dst` and I want to append `src` to the end of `dst`.

I noticed that most answers regarding this task are recommending this:

```
     dst.insert(dst.end(),
                std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()),
                std::make_move_iterator(src.end()));
```

Over this:

```
    dst.insert(dst.end(), src.begin(), src.end());
```

As far as I know, pushing (inserting) elements to a vector requires allocating space for the inserted elements at the end of the vector in both cases to ensure memory contiguity, and I'm assuming that the `copy` and `move` cost is the same in this case.

Moving the objects will make them immediately destroy-able, is that the only benefit of doing so, or is there something else I'm missing?

**edit:**
Can you explain that in those two cases:

1. The vectors contain plain data, ex: int.
2. The vectors contain class objects.

Comment: These two lines are not equivalent - In the first case, you won't be able to use items in `src` after the insertion. In both cases you will allocate memory for the vector, but the first version will *move* items while the second will *copy* them, and moving is cheaper than copying - If your items are big (e.g. vectors), this will make a huge difference.

Comment: Moving is in general cheaper then copying. Why is this surprising?

Comment: Yes, adding the elements always requires more space. But the memory footprint of the process will grow only for the vector, and not also for each element if it hold a pointer to some very big state.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why is moving them more effective .. I'm allocating the memory again in both cases?

Comment: @Baraa You are allocating the memory for the vector cells, not the memory managed by the items. If your vectors contains `string`, you will need to allocate `n` cells in both cases, but if you move, you will only copy a `char*` and a `int` (let's assume basic implementation), whereas if you copy you will need to re-allocate a new `char` array and copy contents for each of the `n` strings.

Comment: Editing a valid question to rule out valid answers you have already gotten is bad cricket.  And now your question is incoherant, as it attaches an important criteria that chamges the answer as an appendix.

Comment: @Yakk, I rolled it back to the earlier version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, if copying and moving an element costs the same (is in your example with elements of type `int`), then there is no difference.

Moving only makes a difference for elements which themselves store their data on the heap, i.e. use allocated memory (for example if the elements are `std::string` or `std::vector<something>`). In this case, moving or copying the elements makes a (potentially huge) difference (provided the move constructor and `operator=(value_type&&)` are properly implemented/enabled), since a move merely copies the pointer to the allocated memory, while a copy is deep: it allocates new memory and copies all data, including recursive deep copies if applicable.

As to the costs associated with the data stored in `std::vector`, there are some costs if the appended elements exceed capacity. In this case, the whole vector will be resized, including moving *all* its elements. The reason for this is that `std::vector`, by specification, stores all its elements in a single array. If appending containers is a frequent operation in your code, you may want to consider other containers, such as `std::list` or `std::deque`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm assuming that the copy and move cost is the same.

You assume wrong.

This has nothing to do with the vector nor the insertion. This has to do with the relative cost difference between the constructor

```
ClassT::ClassT(const ClassT& orig);
```

and

```
ClassT::ClassT(ClassT&& orig);
```

[You can **always** find a move constructor which is **cheaper or equal** to the copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

> A constructor is called a 'move constructor' when it takes an rvalue
>   reference as a parameter. It is not obligated to move anything, the
>   class is not required to have a resource to be moved and a 'move
>   constructor' may not be able to move a resource as in the allowable
>   (but maybe not sensible) case where the parameter is a const rvalue
>   reference (const T&&).

`ClassT` could perform the exact same operations as the copy constructor for instance. Or `ClassT` could perform a better move construction. Which means if you don't need the original instances of the objects in src when inserting in dst, you **should** use a move operation.

Comment: I'm almost sure about that :), but why is it cheaper in this exmple?

Comment: @Baraa we'ld need to know the `value_type` of the vector to answer that.

Comment: Let's assume that it's integer type.

Comment: *Most of the time, you can implement a move construction which is cheaper than a copy construction.* is presumably wrong, but definitely too unspecific.

Comment: @Walter I am trying to find a type for which it doesn't hold. But let me correct.

Comment: moving is *not cheaper* than copy for any type that does not manage allocated memory (either directly or indirectly via its members). Thus, any POD, and builtin types. BTW, I was not one of the downvoters.

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer. But I think a short program can illustrate it well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

struct expansive {
    static unsigned instances;
    static unsigned copies;
    static unsigned assignments;
    expansive() { ++instances; }
    expansive(expansive const&) { ++copies; ++instances; }
    expansive& operator=(expansive const&) { ++assignments; return *this; }
};

unsigned expansive::instances = 0;
unsigned expansive::copies = 0;
unsigned expansive::assignments = 0;

struct handle {
    expansive *h;

    handle() : h(new expansive) { }
    ~handle() { delete h; }

    handle(handle const& other) : h(new expansive(*other.h)) { }
    handle(handle&& other) : h(other.h) { other.h = nullptr; }
    handle& operator=(handle const& other) { *h = *other.h; return *this; }
    handle& operator=(handle&& other)  { std::swap(h, other.h); return *this; }
};

int main() {

  {
      std::vector<handle> v1(10), v2(10);

      v1.insert(end(v1), begin(v2), end(v2));

      std::cout << "When copying there were "
                << expansive::instances   << " instances of the object with " 
                << expansive::copies      << " copies and "
                << expansive::assignments << " assignments made." << std::endl;

  }

    expansive::instances = expansive::copies = expansive::assignments = 0;

  {
    std::vector<handle> v1(10), v2(10);

      v1.insert(end(v1), std::make_move_iterator(begin(v2)),
                       std::make_move_iterator(end(v2)));


      std::cout << "When moving there were "
                << expansive::instances   << " instances of the object with " 
                << expansive::copies      << " copies and "
                << expansive::assignments << " assignments made.\n";
  }

    return 0;
}
```

`expansive` models a resource that's really costly to copy (imagine opening file handles, network connections, etc). That's the resource managed by `handle`. To maintain programs correctness, `handle` must still preform the costly copying when it itself is being copied.

Now, when the program is run, it produces the following output:

> When copying there were 30 instances of the object with 10 copies and
>   0 assignments made.   When moving there were 20 instances of the
>   object with 0 copies and 0 assignments made.

What does it mean? It means, that if we only want to transfer the handles to another container, we have to do some really expansive work along the way (linear in the number of resources we try to transfer). Move semantics come to our rescue here.
By using a `move_iterator`, the actual costly resource is being transferred directly, rather than being replicated superfluously. That can translate to a massive boost in performance.

Comment: good example, anyway they already had me at the string example :)

Comment: @Baraa, I don't blame you :) Just figured it can help future readers if there's an example where they can easily trace what's happening